# Real-Time Speech Diarization Options for Python?

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have a research project where I need to utilize realtime speech diarization between two users and track which user said what. I just want to know what's the best approach and are there any free libraries which can do this in python? The audio will be inputted using a websocket from a user's device into a backend environment.

I've tried utilizing the "Diart" library which can be found [here](https://github.com/juanmc2005/diart), however when I try to install the packages needed on my Mac M1, I get this error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: hmmlearn
  Building wheel for hmmlearn (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [121 lines of output]
```

followed by

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for hmmlearn
  Running setup.py clean for hmmlearn
Failed to build hmmlearn
ERROR: Could not build wheels for hmmlearn, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've tried downgrading to older versions which wouldn't require the "hmmlearn" library, but those also kept failing for similar reasons. I'm just wondering is there any other library or anything else that I could use to make it work?

I know of Google's speech diarization API, however after a free trial you'd have to pay to use it. I'm wondering if there are any "free" options available.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider [`pyannote`](https://github.com/pyannote/pyannote-audio) - a toolkit for speaker diarisation. It has several Google Colab-based notebooks with examples. Requires accepting conditions of use and acquiring a token through Hugging Face.